# Joining Sybase stored proc output in a query

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase

I have a Sybase stored proc with the following interface:

```
myStoredProc @varA int, @varB int OUTPUT
```

I would like to run this proc against another table (TableA) within a query, like follows:

```
SELECT TableA.Id, proc.@result
FROM TableA
   LEFT JOIN (myStoredProc TableA.id, @result OUTPUT) proc
```

I know this won't work, but hopefully you get the idea of what I'm trying to return. Note that the Id values from TableA are passed in as the arg for the proc, and I would like the result set to contain the Id column and the output result from the stored proc.

Is this possible?  Or do I need to loop over the proc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you have a Sybase ASE.

I can't check this now but as far I remember you could connect to the same ASE as external server through Component Interation Server and create remote procedure as proxy table.
Find "Remote procedures as proxy tables" in "Component Integration Services Users Guide".

Also I think that is no good solution for performance.

Comment: Gave you the answer just for the comment on performance.  I ended up extracting parts of the proc and creating a new one that was much more performant.